# How can i submit form with not goto new page in NET Core MVC?(except ajax)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

How many ways to submit a form in NETCore MVC？
I want CRUD in one page ,my idea is use pop-up with diffrent page but i don't want use ajax,
Is there any other place to submit ,I use bootstrap for page,Thanks.

Comment: if you use return Page(); it should reload the same page. AJAX or something like SignalR would be the only option if you want to avoid the page refresh.

Comment: @T3.0: So i just can use Javascript to achieve this?

Comment: You can use like httprequest,fetch,but it is similar with ajax.

Comment: @Yiyi thanks,i hear about fetch before but don't good at that

Comment: I will try your options,learn a lot from your

Answer (score 0):

MVC Core is very adaptable if you want to have Post Back processes that don't exactly follow online tutorials.

Here is an example of how MVC Core (version 3 in this case) is able to glue together the HTML form data into the action of a controller.

I've created a hidden input with some value. It also has a name attribute that is set to the name of a property on the action.

There is a drop down that takes its value from the model using the attribute asp-for="Aggregation". The value is initially set from the Model but will be whichever option the user selects in the web page

I also have a button which will submit the form. On this button, I have added a number of asp- attributes that come from the MVC Core View Model.

```
<form method="post">
    <select class="form-control mr-2" asp-for="Aggregation"
            asp-area="Management"
            asp-controller="Visits"
            asp-action="Index"
            asp-route-sortcolumn="@Model.SortColumn"
            asp-route-sortorder="@(Model.SortDirection)"
            onchange="$('form').submit();">

        <option value="Daily">Daily</option>
        <option value="Weekly">Weekly</option>
        <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
        <option value="Yearly">Yearly</option>
    </select>

    <input type="hidden" value="SomeTestValue" name="myHiddenValue" />

    <button asp-area="Management"
            asp-controller="Visits"
            asp-action="ClearFilter"
            asp-route-sortcolumn="@Model.SortColumn"
            asp-route-sortorder="@(Model.SortDirection)"
            class="btn btn-outline-primary mr-2">
        Clear Filter
    </button>
```

When I click the button, the correct action is called with the required parameters set from the form.

the value of myHiddenValue is set from the name attribute of the hidden input
the value of aggregation is set from the asp-for (which renders name="Aggregation" in the HTML to the client browser)
the value of sortColumn and sortOrder came from the button asp-route values,

You can use a model should you wish, just set the HTML side names to something like myModel.Id, myModel.FirstName, assuming you have an action parameter called myModel - you can also extend this to lists of objects too.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ClearFilter(string myHiddenValue, string aggregation, string sortColumn = "VisitDate", SortOrder sortOrder = SortOrder.Descending)
```

Comment: It isn't go to "ClearFiler" page?or i add redirect in that function? I probably find a nice place to solve my problem

Comment: The ClearFilter button just demonstrates that you can post to any number of different actions - even in different controllers if you want to.. You should create your own CRUD actions and call them by your names from the view

Comment: I probably get it

Comment: That is good. You need to decide when to do a HTTPGET on an action and when to POST to an action. It depends on which processes you want to follow. In various projects I have used the simple GET/POST process you will see in the Microsoft tutorials. Other times i have loaded the index view but with an empty list and then used AJAX to HTTPGET the contents. For CRUD I used Ajax with LAYOUT view as a MODAL dialog to get/post data. There is no right way but I generally pick a mechanism and use it consistently in that project